# migration encoding:.Custom(marshal)

Tags: swift3, alamofire

Because I need to make a json string from a type `Array<Array<Double>>` instead of `Dictionary<String, Any>` I need custom encoding and can't use the default json encoding from alamofire 4.

In alamofire 3 I did this:

```
    let marshal: (URLRequestConvertible, [String: AnyObject]?) -> (NSMutableURLRequest, NSError?) = {
        (urlRequest, parameters) in
        var mutableURLRequest = urlRequest as! NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        mutableURLRequest.httpBody = self.buffer.json()
        return (mutableURLRequest, nil)
    }
```

But I don't know enough swift 3 to be able to understand how I should implement a encoding protocol that I can use in alamofire 4

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol

Can you provide me with a example please that does implement a alamofire 4 encoding protocol.

Based on https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#custom-encoding I tried:

```
    struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
        private let buffer: Array<Array<Double>>
        init(_ buffer: Array<Array<Double>>) {
            self.buffer = buffer
        }
        func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
            var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.httpBody = self.buffer.json()
            return urlRequest
        }
    }
```

`encoding:JSONStringArrayEncoding(self.buffer)` compiles but doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: Nevermind it works :) did something else stupid not related to this, I will just leave it here to help other people. Feel free to answer if you have a better solution then the above.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your json string is:- `{"action":"userLogin","info":{"email":"chandragirish86@gmail.com","password":"qwert123","login":"login"}}`
then you should write the dictionary  below :-

```
let jsonObject: [String: Any] = ["action":Urls.loginUrl,
                                         "info":["email":"chandragirish86@gmail.com","password":"qwert123","login":"login"]]
```

Then you just call the Alamofire post function with json encoding:-

```
Alamofire.request (url, method: .post, parameters: jsonObject,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.data{

                    let json:JSON = JSON(data: data)
                    completionHandler(json,nil)
                }
                break
            case .failure(_):
                print("URL> \(url)...\(response.result.error as Any)")
                completionHandler(nil,response.result.error as NSError?)
                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: That just the default json solution that doesn't even use custom encoding or a Array<Array<Double>> as input

Comment: if you want to convert anyobject to json (if valid) then just use 
`do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
    // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

    // you can now cast it with the right type        
    if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
        // use dictFromJSON
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}`

Comment: Maybe so but thats why the `encoding:` is for, my question was specifically how to use the alamofire 4 encoding protocol. I fail to see how this answer fit the question.